# Figuring out what OS is on which partition?

Tags: filesystems, partition, system-installation, dual-boot

So I have both Ubuntu and Crunchbang installed on my laptop, and I'm trying to figure out which one is on which partition.

I'm going to install another OS (probably BT) and need to know what partition can safely be wiped.

Any tips ?

My partitions at the moment:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `grub` installed, run `os-prober` as root. It does exactly what you want.

**Update**

`os-prober` will only list operating systems other than the one it's on: it's used by GRUB during installation to generate `grub.cfg` so it's natural that GRUB doesn't need info about the OS it's being installed on. To get the partition mounted as the current `/`, you can do this:

```
ROOT_PARTITION="$(readlink -e -- "$(findmnt /|awk 'END{print $2}')")"
```

This will fail in the unlikely case that the partition mounted as `/` has a space in its name.

#### References

- [GRUB 2 bootloader - Full tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId835620)

Comment: Incidentally when I run that command it only reports my windows partitions, should it show all of them? I'm running it in a shell, `sudo os-prober`, is that OK?

Comment: @slm When I run it on my system it reports all installed OSs but the one I'm on. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I'll edit the answer to work around that.

Comment: OK so it must not be working b/c I only have Windows + Fedora on this laptop, so it can't detect mounted partitions would be my guess. Perhaps if they're readonly mounted?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For me too, it only gives me where Ubuntu's partition when I run it from Crunchbang. Any way that it can give me all the OS's and partitions?

Comment: @JosephR. Actually, that helped, I just booted on Ubuntu and ran it again to figure out Debian 7 (which I'm assuming is Crunchbang here) is on `/dev/sda7`. As for Ubuntu itself, I found before it was on `/dev/sda1`.
Now that brings me to a different question: on `/dev/sda6` I have my /home used by Ubuntu. How should I go about installing BT ? Can I move what's on `/dev/sda6` to `/dev/sda1`, or can I just partition it and then install a new OS ?
Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `blkid` to see what type of filesystem is on a given partition:

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows7_OS" UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Lenovo_Recovery" UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_swap: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: It would have helped me if I had the LABELs too, but I only get the UUID back, which doesn't tell me much :/

Comment: @anas - yes this is only helpful if you've labeled your partitions. JosephR.'s approach is probably the best.

Answer (score 2):

`cat /etc/*-release`

Can be used from the terminal, just mount the partitions, then

`cat /dev/sda6/etc/*-release; cat /dev/sda7/etc/*-release`

Comment: This file is what's used by `lsb_release` when you run this via the command line on a Linux box. See `man lsb_release`.

Comment: you could run `lsb_release -a` but you would have to `chroot` to which ever root directory you wanted to check first.

Comment: `cat /etc/*-release` only gives me my current OS, and it doesn't give me the partition it's on

Comment: You should make that clearer in your response.